# Looping through rows of a particular column by searching for a string

Tags: r, string, if-statement, dataframe

I imported some data from a txt file:

```
df <- read.table(file.choose(), 
                               sep = "\t",
                               skip = 2,
                               fill = T)
df <- cdf[,c(6,11)]
colnames(df) <- c("area", "population")
```

A shortened version of my data looks like this in the environment in RStudio

```
     area                                      population
[1]  area0                                     0
[2]  area1:                                    59,859
[3]  area0:                                    56000
[4]  area0:                                    25
[5]  area0:                                    Unknown
[6]  area0:                                    1,400
```

This is in a `data.frame` class and I want to loop through the `state` to find if it contains the phrase `area0`. If it does, I want to go to `population` on that same row and add the populations up via a cumulative sum. My end result should be like this:
`area0 57425` in a new data.frame

Comment: Ideally , this would have worked `sum(as.numeric(as.character(df$population[grepl("Washington", df$state)])), na.rm = T)` but there are some issues in `Population` column. It has been read as characters. So you first need to remove all the commas using `gsub`. For example, `59,859` should be changed to `59859` and then use the above code.

Comment: Then what does it do? Did you assign the value back to the column ?  `customerStateAndPopOE$population <- gsub(",", "", customerStateAndPopOE$population)`

Comment: @RonakShah Ok yes. I was not assigning the value back. The `gsub` worked now and the commas are removed. When I do the `sum()` code I get this error in the console: `Error in df$population : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

EDIT: Never mind I understand why I was getting that error. I did not replaced `df` with the name of my data frame. Thank you for your help, I am just learning R.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop here. After you replaced the commas, you need to do `sum(as.numeric(as.character(customerStateAndPopOE$population[grepl("Washington"‌​, customerStateAndPopOE$state])), na.rm = T) `

Comment: Check the enclosing brackets. `na.rm` should be in the outermost bracket, doesn't look like it in the gif at least. Also the brackets before that doesn't look properly aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ronak Shah stated in the comments, this problem can be solved using
`sum(as.numeric(as.character(df$population‌​[grepl("area0"‌‌​​, df$state])), na.rm = T)`

This avoids the need need for a for loop.

A second thing that should be implemented is getting rid of the commas in the `population` column so the sum can be calculated correctly. This can be done using `gsub`:

```
df$population <- gsub(",", "", df$population)
```

Comment: Saw your thanks but, as I didn't get to it until after you had deleted your other questions, I missed everything after "I will follow your re…", if there was anything. PS Forgot to mention that if you delete those questions, you will get back the rep you lost. PPS Also forgot to suggest you should accept this answer (by clicking on the gray/blank tick) so others can tell that the problem has been solved.

Comment: Oops! Keep forgetting about the 2 day delay. Also note that now you are at 15+ rep, you can up-vote any question/answer.